# Why is the force due to a charged loop on a charge on its axis only in the axial direction?

Tags: forces, vectors, coulombs-law

This may be more of a mathematics question, but I am going through the open course for physics II, from Yale, and am learning about Coulomb's Law. One of the first examples the professor gives is finding the force a wire exerts on a charge.

[image: practice problem image]

When taking the entire setup into account, the equation to find the force on the charge is:

[image: equation for charge]

This makes sense to me. However, what I am trying to better understand is what the professor does next - he removes the other forces other than those along the z-axis, because of the fact that the forces along the x-axis will cancel, and the resultant equation is the following:

[image: equation with question]

I believe that the reason for having $z/\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}$ multiplied by the expression is to have the ratio of the length of $z$ compared to the length of $r$, which somehow cancels out $r$. But I am having some difficulty understanding intuitively why he uses $z/\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}$ to get the force from only the z-axis. Can anyone explain this to me to help me understand it more intuitively, or refer me to a place where I can learn better what he is doing? Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with trigonometry? $\cos \theta = z/\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}$.

Comment: So, you are calling theta the angle between z and r, where z is the adjacent side and r=sqrt(R^2 + z^2) is the hypotenuse? If so, then that makes sense. Where I'm having a hang up is this: what does that mean? For example, how does that make it so that it is just the z-component of the force? Forgive me if I am being slow - I need to brush up on my trigonometry.

Comment: Maybe to better clarify what I am asking - why is it that we use cos(theta) instead of sin(theta)?

Comment: See my answer for details. I didn't define $\theta$, it is defined in your first figure. If you draw the triangle formed by separating $d\vec{F}$ into its components, $dF_z$ will be the length of the side adjacent to $\theta$, hence the $\cos \theta$ factor. This is basic trigonometry, and follows immediately from the definition of $\cos$. $\sin \theta$ does not make sense: if $\theta$ were zero, $\sin \theta = 0$ would mean there would be no z-component, which is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The force on the charge due to the piece of the wire at coordinates $(x, y, 0)$ can be decomposed into two components, one along the z-axis, and one parallel to the xy-plane. The force due to the piece at coordinates $(-x, -y, 0)$ (i.e. on the opposite side of the loop) also has two such components, except the component parallel to the xy-plane is precisely the opposite of the same component due to the piece at $(x, y, 0)$. Owing to this symmetry, you can immediately tell that the total force on the charge will not have an xy-component, so you only need to calculate the z-component due to each segment of the wire.

If you draw the components of the force $d\vec{F}$ on your first figure so that they form a right triangle, you will see that the z-component of the force is  $$ dF_z = dF \cos\theta= dF \frac{z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}} $$
which explains where this factor comes from. If you don't wish to use trigonometry at all, you can arrive at the same result by using the similarity of this triangle formed by the components of $d\vec{F}$, and the right triangle with sides $z$, $R$ and $r$.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to draw it also out to see it better, but this makes sense.